# JavaPOS library

Tags: java, javapos

I am trying to find .jar library for JavaPOS implementation for days, and yet I couldn't find anything to work. I found a lot of documentations like this one : http://jpos.1045706.n5.nabble.com/file/n2250344/StarReceiptTest.java and a jar file : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjposjar.htm but it seems it's not the one I can use with the documentation above. If there is someone who knows about this or could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried that one but i can not find the jar to put in the build path

Comment: Do you have an idea of how do i implement it in Eclipse ?

Comment: You can find lib at jpos.org/download. Jpos also provide good document for starter http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf

Comment: I already did that but there is no jar file in there : http://postimg.org/image/550ykn5hr/

Comment: It used by gradle to build newest jar file, or you can use maven. Read here https://github.com/jpos/jPOS

Comment: There is link to a download page on http://jpos.org/resources.  (The download page itself is behind a signup page ...)

Answer (score 1):

We use maven dependency for including jPOS in our project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```